# File extension for serialized protobuf output

Tags: protocol-buffers

Seems odd that I can't find the answer to this, but what file extension are you supposed to use when storing serialized protobuf output in a file?  Just .protobuf? The json equivalent of what I am talking about would be a .json file.

Comment: .pb seems to be used pretty often also

Comment: How about `.pb.bin`? 
Seems clear and uses the double dot syntax like the code generated files (e.g. .pb.swift)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I just use .bin, but there's no actual standard here AFAIK. If `protoc -o` (which emits a .proto schema in protobuf binary format as a `FileDescriptorSet`) had taken a directory like all the other output options do, we could have used that as a de-facto answer, but `protoc -o` is unusual in that it takes a file instead. In an old post on the protobuf group, Kenton Varda (one of the original authors) suggests that the file extension should be implementation specific (meaning: *you* decide) rather than simply referring to the format: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/protobuf/JWZx9n8CUvw

Answer (score 6):

According to the [documentation](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/techniques/#suffixes), the recommended file extensions are:

- Text Format: `.txtpb`
- Wire Format: `.binpb`
- JSON Format: `.json`