# What MIME type should my Protobuf Swagger API use?

Tags: azure, swagger, mime, protobuf-net, azure-functions

I have a custom protobuf output/input for an Azure Function.

- What is an appropriate MIME format for this?

If it's true that there is no generic protobuf reader, and that the client would need a custom parser for my application specific protobuf output, then that makes me think

```
mime: application/myAppName+Protobuf
```

... is appropriate (without the plus sign).

What other rationale should I consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think about MIME types in the same way as file extensions, and on the topic of protobuf, the advice is that [the extension should reflect your usage, not the fact that it is protobuf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44577730/23354).

If we use the same approach, then perhaps just `application/myAppName`. But ultimately, as long as your consumers understand your intent, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Suppose I have a JSON endpoint and Protobuf, should the accept mime header reflect the protocol then?